# cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I know this is kind of duplicate question but I tested the solutions mentioned in the questions and got nothing.still have problem.I recently have installed rails 4.0.0 and ruby 2.0.0 and I get error when I want to start rails server by:

```
rails s
```

I confront with :

```
/home/pooya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
```

And there is something weird here.my sqlite3 version is 3.7.9 while it is 1.3.7 in the code error!

what to do?

Comment: What command are you running? Try to elaborate your question.

Comment: rails s ! ( I thought it was obvious )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error "no such file to load" -- sqlite3/sqlite3\_native (LoadError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800920/error-no-such-file-to-load-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror)

Comment: my platform is Ubuntu 12.04 while it was windows 7.

Comment: looks like a possible duplicate, but the solution brought up in that thread don't seem to make any difference. I get the same error with Ruby 2.0 32bit railsinstaller with devkit.

Comment: Maybe you meet this question. The answer is good. I fixed it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails/17762417#17762417

Answer (score 0):

While I was trying to play around Amazon Linux, I too faced the same

```
"/usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)"
```

Since everything was already setup on my local, I tried debugging.

The issue apparently is the library is missing in

```
/usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/
```

If you go to this path, you will see that sqlite3_native.so is not present.

What I did was simply, ran a locate sqlite3_native.so and copied it to the location.

I faced the same issue with all other libraries in Amazon Linux, including nokogiri and nodejs.