# cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError) on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

When I try to setup basic installation and initiation of server using Rails 4.0.0 on Ruby 2.0.0, I'm facing the following error message.

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/penchal/new/site/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

How can I avoid this error message and proceed further?

Comment: what OS are you trying this on?

Comment: Seems to be a windows problem. Solutions vary. See if this will do for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/6126062/2576857 .

Comment: But it doesn't seem that he is using windows. Maybe [this article](http://ahmedemad.wordpress.com/2013/05/17/ruby-on-rails-install-run-error/) would be of help.

Comment: Oh yeah, /usr/local/etc, saw that now, my bad. From what I found, most people having this problem was because of sqlite exe and dll not in PATH variable, but that only happened to windows users. I think that article you provided should hit the nail on the head, but let's wait and see.

Comment: If Rails 4 and Ruby 2.1. - look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365791/sqlite3-loaderror-incompatible-library-version/37457006#37457006)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Find your sqlite3 gemspec file. One example is  `/usr/local/share/gem/specifications/sqlite3-1.3.7.gemspec`

Windows: 
`C:\Ruby21\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\specifications`.

You should adjust according with your Rubygem path and sqlite3 version.
Edit the file above and look for the following line

```
s.require_paths=["lib"]
```

change it to

```
s.require_paths= ["lib/sqlite3_native"]
```

Comment: This is a fantastic error to a problem which shouldn't exist in the first place, given the number of Rails users on Windows. I would love to know why exactly this works though...

Comment: This worked for 1.3.9 but was not necessary for 1.3.11. I'm on Win7 x64.

Comment: sweet fix thank you.   Not sure how you came up with this but it fixed my problem for ruby 2.1.0

Comment: Worked for me, but I don't want to get more new erros.

Comment: It already presented and error: Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.

Comment: the above error with the adapter doesn't seem to be solvable, doing what hwding suggests below first would save me quite some time - again though, maybe they'll fix that in the next releases, or fixed that in stacked packages like RailsInstaller (ruby2.3.1 with devkit(mingw with build tools), rails5.0.0.1)

p.s. it's unbelievable that this problem still persists, after 2 years - given that sqlite is used by default in the skeleton default application, and is the way to go in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Two years? How about THREE years?

Answer (score 21):

Since [pull request #229](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/pull/229) has been merged, sqlite3 can be installed per `git:` key. It's possible to use sqlite3 easily through this addition in your `Gemfile` :

```
gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby"
```

This works on RubyInstaller-2.4 and newer. It automatically installs the required pacman package `mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3` when you run `bundler install`.

There are some more hints for Rails on Windows in the [RubyInstaller2 FAQ](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/wiki/FAQ#q-are-there-recommendations-for-working-with-rails).

Comment: This answer is helpful for the new ruby installers ruby version **ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029)** and rails version **Rails 5.2.1**

Comment: The PR has been merged in the meanwhile. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: To get around SSL issues I used: gem 'sqlite3', git: "git://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby.git"

Comment: probably no longer need the git repo

Answer (score 20):

see：https://stackoverflow.com/a/39136421/6755206

fortunately, you don't have to switch to ruby 2.0
there is a solution to this issue, after endless trying...

https://github.com/hwding/sqlite3-ruby-win

---

## Steps

#### Pre

- `gem uninstall sqlite3 --all`

#### Source

- Download the latest sqlite3-ruby, https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby
- unzip the package

#### Build

- run command-line in the extracted dir
- make sure you have your C compiler installed and added to PATH
- `gem install bundler`
- `bundle install`
- `rake native gem`
- you'll find a dir named 'pkg' generated

#### Install

- enter dir 'pkg'
- `gem install --local sqlite3-xxx.gem` ('xxx' is version code)

#### Check

- `irb`
- `require 'sqlite3'`

Comment: Thanks @hwding. This works perfectly! In my case, Windows user, it seems like two sqlite3 versions (32 and 64 bits) were compiled in 'pkg', but I just installed the 64bits one (my case).

Comment: yes, after a lot of trying, this is the only way that worked.... other people (https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/30s1cz/rails_on_windows_not_being_cooperative/) suggest moving to something like vagrant and skipping Windows+Rails altogether

Comment: I confirm this is the only solution working for windows 10; tried a couple of fixes but this is the only one working.

Comment: I have done according to the steps mentioned, but I don't see any folder created with the name `pkg`.

Comment: Worked for me up to `you'll find a dir named 'pkg' generated` as I didn't see such a directory anywhere. @Edson Momm's solution below worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

```
gem uninstall sqlite3 --all
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3
gem inst sqlite3 --platform ruby
```

This solved the problem to me.

```
Windows 10
Ruby 2.5.3
Rails 5.2.2
```

Comment: OMG is this real :D Only this works for me, Windows 10 is terrible for RoR. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Worked also for me. My problem started after an update from ruby 2.4 to ruby 2.6 on windows 10.

Comment: This was the answer for me as well on Win10 Ruby 2.6 (x64). Thank you!

Comment: I actually had to do this a few times. Seems that any time I would do a `bundle install` in order to install a new gem, I would run into this issue again and would need to repeat the above steps.

Answer (score 9):

Just edit Gemfile and add  `gem 'sqlite3', platform: :ruby`.

Answer (score 6):

No compiling of the sources or downloading pre-compiled libraries will solve this problem, believe me I tried everything, the problem lies somewhere else. This is how it works on windows:

`bundle update sqlite3`

You likely get another similar error after this one regarding nokogiri, fix it with the command:

`bundle update nokogiri`

Enjoy your Ruby App!

Answer (score 4):

Uninstalling and reinstalling the sqlite3 gem worked for me.

```
gem uninstall sqlite3

bundle
```

Answer (score 4):

If the top answer doesn't work, a fix that I discovered is simply going to your Gemfile and adding the version number 1.3.11 (instead of 1.3.9) right after sqlite3. So the line in your Gemfile should now read:

```
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3',  '1.3.11'
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"
```

Answer (score 4):

**BEST OFFICIAL INSTALL**

Im using rails 5.2.1p57, Windows 10
Just running following lines sloved the problem

```
gem uninstall sqlite3
```

and uninstall all installed versions. again execute following command

```
gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby
```

You are now done.
Let me know if problem persist.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when I upgrade my Ruby version to 2.5.X. I tracked with  `rails task --trace` that the sqlite3 is not available to version 2.5, than I change my GemFile the gem "sqlite3" change to "sqlite3-ruby", after I uninstall the gem "sqlite3" and finally I run the `bundle install`.

I don't know what is the reason... I read that "sqlite3" is not available for ruby 2.5 yet, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this error, ensure that `gem sqlite3` is added to your Gemfile.
Then extract "exe"s and "dll"s from [Sqlite download link](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) to Ruby's bin folder.
If problem still persists. Try this:

`bundle update`

`gem uninstall sqlite3`

Given a choice between multiple versions of sqlite3,  choose last option 'All versions'. Enter last number here

> Select gem to uninstall:
>   1. sqlite3-1.3.13
>   2. sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32
>   3. All versions
>   >`3`
>   .
>   .
>   If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
>   Continue with Uninstall? [yN]
>   >
>   `y`

`gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby`

`rails s`

This should work.

Read through this [link](http://wikiprogramming.org/linux/ruby-2-5-1-windows-fix-cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3_native-loaderror/) for more explanation if above works for you.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well. It turned out that I had originally installed SQLite 1.3.10, but then I copied some gems from the Rails tutorial screencasts project and it listed SQLite 1.3.9. Then I got the same error you did. I changed it back to 1.3.10 and it worked.

(This is on Windows 7. I was running the screencast tutorial on Cloud9 IDE).

Answer (score 1):

This is the only solution worked for me, derived from [this GitHub issue post](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/185#issuecomment-221722160):

1. Get autoconf version of sqlite3 sources from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html.
2. Start MSYS shell.
3. In unpacked location for your sqlite3, configure static version only to avoid keeping DLL on PATH: `./configure --disable-shared`.
4. Build and install it: `make install DESTDIR=/c/dev/ruby/tmp`. You can change the directory.
5. Open command prompt of windows and run `gem uninstall sqlite3 --all` to remove all existing sqlite3 gems.
6. Again on command prompt of windows, build and install sqlite3 gem: `gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby -- --with-sqlite3-include=C:\dev\ruby\tmp\usr\local\include --with-sqlite3-lib=C:\dev\ruby\tmp\usr\local\lib`. Those include and lib directories may be different, so check at first.

I am using Ruby version 2.5.1 and Rails version 5.2.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: and gemspec file in the Gem's source folder

Answer (score 1):

i found it! i saw this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsrzvX0qzmA

i instaled:
    Rails version: 5.2.1
    Ruby version: 2.5.3 (x64-mingw32)
Sqlite version 1.3.13
and i have your problem...
my solution:

1. In your installing folder like C:\Ruby25-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.5.0\gems\
       you have folders:
       "sqlite3-1.3.13"
       "sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32"
2. Find file
        C:\Ruby25-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.5.0\gems\sqlite3-1.3.13\lib\sqlite3\sqlite3_native.so
3. Copy it in C:\Ruby25-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.5.0\gems\sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32\lib\sqlite3\2.5\sqlite3_native.so
        (may be folders not exist - create and paste)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

Adding the below to the Gemfile fixed for me:
gem 'sqlite3', '1.4.0', platforms: :ruby

Answer (score 1):

Change your sqlite3 gem in the Gemfile for this:

```
gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"
```

Then run:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

For OSX users, this can result from using a ruby manager (e.g. rvm).

If you edit your ~/.bash_profile and add this:

```
[[ "$APP" = *"/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/"* ]] && {
  echo Xcode detected
  rvm use system
}
```

You can work around the issue. Restart Xcode before attempting to build again.

The actual issue is tracked here: https://openradar.appspot.com/28726736).

Full credit goes to: https://egeek.me/2018/04/14/ipa-export-error-in-xcode-and-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same probe but its quite simple,

```
gem uninstall sqlite3 --all
```

then run

```
gem install sqlite3
```

everything should work well from there.

Answer (score -1):

I tried:
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
Then I tried:
gem install sqlite3
And it worked

Comment: `gem install sqlite3` has already been mentioned in other answers.

Comment: I tried gem install sqlite3 and it didn't work, while "sudo apt-get install sqlite3" worked.

Comment: Your comment says the opposite of what your answer says.