# Can't start rails server - sqlite3 adapter error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to teach myself ruby on rails and I'm trying to create a simple application to start with. I'm following the tutorial at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-rails-project but am having difficulty starting the server. When I try start up the server and go to the localhost,

```
Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in
config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or
'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.
```

I'm tried to look up a solution/reason why this happens on other questions but to no avail.

My Gemfile looks like this

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:
https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

I'm using 
Ruby 2.1.3

and when I type

> gem list

I find I'm running 
rails 4.1.6
sqlite3 (1.3.9 x86-mingw32)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load 'active\_record/connection\_adapters/sqlite3\_adapter'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277968/could-not-load-active-record-connection-adapters-sqlite3-adapter)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `config/database.yml` has an appropriate database driver set for current environment:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3 # check if you have sqlite3 here
  encoding: ...
  database: ...
  pool: ...
  username: ...
  password: ...
```

Also don't forget to set it for all other environments you want to use sqlite3 in.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used sqlite but from the error I'm guessing you have a line in `database.yml` that says:

```
adapter: sqlite3_adapter
```

that should instead be:

```
adapter: sqlite3
```

Edit: ninja'd

Answer (score 0):

You can put your sqlite3 gem to development in Gemfile

> group :development do
>     gem 'sqlite3'
>    //*Your other gem to only development
>   end

Answer (score -1):

wrong adapter in your database.yml file.
use this:

```
adapter: sqlite3
```