# Getting a LoadError in browser after executing rails generate controller StaticPages help contact

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I know running ruby on rails on Windows has a lot of issues but I cannot do much until I get a new laptop running Linux or OSx.

This is another issue which I am facing randomly. I was able to fix it last time after a lot of trial and error so I have now forgot how to fix it. 
Here are the things I did so far,

1. Created a new rails application
2. Ran rails generate controller StaticPages home help 
   Everything was ok. I see that new static pages are created but when I run the rails server and hit localhost:3000/static_pages/home I am seeing this below error in the browser response,

   Started GET "/static_pages/home" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-28 15:21:13 +1100

   ```
   LoadError (Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter'. M
   ake sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter
    other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapt
   er gem to the Gemfile.):
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in requ
   ire'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependen
   ```

   activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
     activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:
   6:in`'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`block in requ
   ire'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependen
   cy'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'
     activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specific
   ation.rb:175:in `spec'
     activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in`establish
   _connection'
     activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in
   <class:Railtie>'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in`instance_ev
   al'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hoo
   k'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in`block in ru
   n_load_hooks'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in`run_load_ho
   oks'
     activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/base.rb:316:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
     activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in`'
     activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:384:in `connection'
     activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:371:in`call'
     actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in
    call'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in`call'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in`_run_call_callba
   cks'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
     actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call'
     actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
     actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in`call'
     actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `c
   all'
     actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`ca
   ll'
     railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
     railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tag
   ged'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`tagged'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
     railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call'
     actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
     rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in`call'
     rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
     activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware
   .rb:28:in`call'
     rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
     actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in`call'
     rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
     railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in`call'
     railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
     rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
     rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'

   ```
     rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
     C:/row/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `s
   ervice'
     C:/row/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `ru
   n'
     C:/row/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block
    in start_thread'


     Rendered C:/row/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4
   .2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
     Rendered C:/row/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4
   .2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.0ms)
     Rendered C:/row/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4
   .2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html
   .erb (1.0ms)
     Rendered C:/row/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4
   .2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb withi
   n rescues/layout (58.0ms)
   ```

There was a similar question here [Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277968/could-not-load-active-record-connection-adapters-sqlite3-adapter) but the solution is not accepted by the person who asked the quesion. I also tried it and it did not work for me.

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                '4.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.1'
gem 'uglifier',             '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',         '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',         '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',           '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',             '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                 '0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  #gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activejob (= 4.2.0)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      rack (~> 1.6.0)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    actionview (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    activejob (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.0)
      activemodel (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.0)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    ansi (1.5.0)
    arel (6.0.0)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (3.4.0)
      columnize (~> 0.8)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2)
      slop (~> 3.6)
    celluloid (0.16.0)
      timers (~> 4.0.0)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.3.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.3.0)
    ffi (1.9.6-x86-mingw32)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    globalid (0.3.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    guard (2.12.4)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (~> 2.7)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-minitest (2.3.1)
      guard (~> 2.0)
      minitest (>= 3.0)
    hike (1.2.3)
    hitimes (1.2.2-x86-mingw32)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.2.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.0.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.2)
    listen (2.8.5)
      celluloid (>= 0.15.2)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
    loofah (2.0.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    lumberjack (1.0.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (2.4.3)
    mini_backtrace (0.1.3)
      minitest (> 1.2.0)
      rails (>= 2.3.3)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.5.1)
    minitest-reporters (1.0.5)
      ansi
      builder
      minitest (>= 5.0)
      ruby-progressbar
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    nenv (0.2.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2-x86-mingw32)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    notiffany (0.0.6)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    pg (0.17.1-x86-mingw32)
    pry (0.10.1-x86-mingw32)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
      win32console (~> 1.3)
    rack (1.6.0)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.0)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activejob (= 4.2.0)
      activemodel (= 4.2.0)
      activerecord (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.0)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.5)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.1)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
    rb-inotify (0.9.5)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
    ruby-progressbar (1.7.1)
    sass (3.4.13)
    sass-rails (5.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    sdoc (0.4.0)
      json (~> 1.8)
      rdoc (~> 4.0, < 5.0)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spring (1.1.3)
    sprockets (2.12.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.2.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.9-x86-mingw32)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.4)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    timers (4.0.1)
      hitimes
    turbolinks (2.3.0)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2015.1)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    uglifier (2.5.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    win32console (1.3.2-x86-mingw32)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug (= 3.4.0)
  coffee-rails (= 4.1.0)
  guard-minitest (= 2.3.1)
  jbuilder (= 2.2.3)
  jquery-rails (= 4.0.3)
  mini_backtrace (= 0.1.3)
  minitest-reporters (= 1.0.5)
  pg (= 0.17.1)
  rails (= 4.2.0)
  rails_12factor (= 0.0.2)
  sass-rails (= 5.0.1)
  sdoc (= 0.4.0)
  spring (= 1.1.3)
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.9)
  turbolinks (= 2.3.0)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (= 2.5.3)
```

database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Update: 
rails s command is throwing this exception now,

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x86-mingw32/l
ib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (L
oadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-
x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-
x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/work/sample_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top
(required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Appreciate if someone could help me out here..

Comment: add your database.yml

Comment: @mohommad AbuShady.. Why exactly? I am using sqlite3 and I have added that in my Gemfile

Comment: because the error is complaining about your `database.yml`, so just wanted to take a look

Comment: `bundle install` didn't complain ?

Comment: you have `pg` in the production group, but it has sqlite in the database.yml, if you are running in production environment then this is the problem, replace the `pg` gem with sqlite as the ones in the `development`, `testing` environments

Comment: bundle install didn't complain.

Comment: I am not running in production environment. I am running in my local system. I am still facing the same issue

Comment: so running `rails s` works fine, but when you refresh the page u get a database error? seems kinda odd

Comment: yes. It was working earlier. Ruby on Rails on Windows is odd i guess.. never seen others complain such things

Comment: Can you open irb and run this code? ```require 'sqlite3'; db = SQLite3::Database.new "test.db"```

Comment: @matugm 
C:\row\RailsInstaller\workspace\sample_app2>irb
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
irb(main):001:0> require 'sqlite3'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3
        from C:/row/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/c
ore_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
        from C:/row/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/c
ore_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
        from

Comment: your problem is that your sqlite driver isn't accessible by ruby anymore, you have two solutions, either double check your sqlite driver, or use something else like `mysql2` ( if it's easier for you )

Comment: Can't I uninstall and reinstall the sqlite driver? i tried gem uninstall sqlite3 and reinstalled it.. still same issue. Any cleanup I can do? This issue started all of a sudden and I was not facing this till yesterday

Comment: Ok. I have no idea how it worked but it did this time. I ran gem uninstall sqlite3 (all versions) and reinstalled it again using gem install sqlite3 
I was not just able to run the rails server but also no errors seen in the browser this time :)
So if anyone else facing this issue please try this solution out more than once!

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the version of sqlite3 that you are using. Try out

```
gem 'sqlite3', '>= 1.3.9'
```

Instead of

```
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.9'
```