# unable to start rails server on windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, webserver

I am following a ruby tutorial and when running '`rails s`' am getting this error.

This was working fine before but now I can't start the rails server now. It seems like I have changed something in rails.

> Booting WEBrick
>   Rails 4.1.5 application starting in development on 
>   Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
>   Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0
>   0.1 (--binding option)
>   Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>   xiting
>   :/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/act
>   ve_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': cannot load such file -- syslogger
>   (LoadError)
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
>   .1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`block in require'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
>   .1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
>   .1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`require'
>          from c:/Sites/omrails/config/environment.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
>   .1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`require'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
>   .1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
>   .1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in`load_dependency'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
>   .1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
>          from c:/Sites/omrails/config.ru:3:in`block in '
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
>   rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
>   rack/builder.rb:55:in`initialize'
>          from c:/Sites/omrails/config.ru:in `new'
>          from c:/Sites/omrails/config.ru:in`'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
>   rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
>   rack/builder.rb:49:in`new_from_string'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
>   rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
>   rack/server.rb:277:in`build_app_and_options_from_config'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
>   rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5
>   lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in`app'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
>   rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5
>   lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in`log_to_stdout'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5
>   lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5
>   lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in`block in server'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5
>   lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5
>   lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in`server'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5
>   lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
>          from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.5
>   lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`'
>          from bin/rails:4:in `require'
>          from bin/rails:4:in`'

****                                      Edit
I tried to reinstall rails and now i have this error when starting rails server****

> C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/de
>   pendencies.rb:247:in `require': cannot load such file --
>   sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/acti
>   ve_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`block in require'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/acti
>   ve_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/acti
>   ve_support/dependencies.rb:247:in`require'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x64-mingw32/li
>   b/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x64-mingw32/li
>   b/sqlite3.rb:2:in`'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/ru
>   ntime.rb:76:in `require'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/ru
>   ntime.rb:76:in`block (2 levels) in require'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/ru
>   ntime.rb:72:in `each'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/ru
>   ntime.rb:72:in`block in require'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/ru
>   ntime.rb:61:in `each'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/ru
>   ntime.rb:61:in`require'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb
>   :133:in `require'
>           from C:/Sites/omrails/config/application.rb:7:in`'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/com
>   mands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/com
>   mands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in`block in server'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/com
>   mands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/com
>   mands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in`server'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/com
>   mands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
>           from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/com
>   mands.rb:17:in`'
>           from bin/rails:4:in `require'
>           from bin/rails:4:in`'

Comment: For the new one after reinstall have you installed sqlite3? Looks like in your config.rb you set your db to sqlite

Comment: yes i installed sqlite3 during the reinstall. I dont have a config.rb file what i have is config.ru

Comment: nayoso meant probably database.yml. Did sqlite3 also compile successfully? It is a native gem that requires a compilation step. I do not develop on windows since years, but I remember it was a pain in the *** to get it compiled...

Answer (score 1):

## Where is the problem?

> You're using the ***sqlite3*** database for **Rails** on *Windows*!

I also got similar error warnings on my Windows 10!

---

## Where is the error located?

> The errors are in your ***gemspec*** folder!

Find your ***gemspec*** folder on your *Windows 8*: 
`C:\Ruby21\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\specifications`.

If you're using [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en) go under: `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\specifications`!

---

## Repair it manually

> You should adjust according with your Rubygem path and sqlite3 version.

Edit the files for

- **sqlite3**-4.1.5.gemspec
- **activesupport**-4.1.5.gemspec
- **rack**-4.1.5.gemspec
- **railties**-4.1.5.gemspec

and look for the following line:

```
s.require_paths=["lib"]
```

change it to:

```
s.require_paths= ["lib/sqlite3_native"]
```

---

## Helpful links

> Your question is similar to [cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError) on ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails/17762417#17762417)!