# Rails Server Sqlite LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

When trying to run `rails server` command from the command line I get the following error. The first line seems the most pertinent, as the ones that follow appear to be errors due to the `LoadError`. However, I'm not really sure.

```
J:\Github\rails\genepool>rails server
J:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
    from J:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from J:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from J:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from J:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from J:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from J:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from J:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from J:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from J:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
    from J:/Github/rails/genepool/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from J:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
    from J:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
    from J:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from J:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from J:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from J:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I have Sqlite3 installed to my Ruby root folder (Ruby21/sqlite). I've also got the Sqlite3 gem installed and the installation returns no errors. I can run sqlite from the command prompt. This is the same way I've got it installed on my laptop, which works fine so I'm really at a loss here. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails) link. You basically have to change the require path from

```
s.require_paths=["lib"]
```

to

```
s.require_paths= ["lib/sqlite3_native"]
```

You can find it in your sqlite3 gemspec file. One example is /usr/local/share/gem/specifications/sqlite3-1.3.7.gemspec or 'C:\Ruby21\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\specifications'.

Comment: I saw that solution and it didn't work for me. The thing is, I'm using the same set-up on my laptop and Sqlite is working just fine without that modification. This error it returns doesn't mean anything to me so it's difficult to know exactly what the problem is. Thanks for trying, I appreciate it.