# Trouble starting Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a newbie in Ruby. I have installed ruby and gems in in windows system but unable to start rails server. I have attached the screen shot and the below the error i am getting. Need help to sort this out.

```
c:\ror\dev\draft_app>rails s
c:/ror/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb
:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
        from c:/ror/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x86-mingw32/l
ib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from c:/ror/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x86-mingw32/l
ib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/ror/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:76:in `require'
        from c:/ror/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from c:/ror/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:72:in `each'
        from c:/ror/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from c:/ror/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:61:in `each'
        from c:/ror/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:61:in `require'
        from c:/ror/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler.rb
:134:in `require'
        from c:/ror/dev/draft_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/ror/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from c:/ror/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from c:/ror/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from c:/ror/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from c:/ror/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from c:/ror/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/com
mands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Instead of including the image, please copy the full error stack and include it in the question. The error details in the image are hardly visible.

Comment: I'll give you same advice I am giving to anyone trying ruby on windows - don't, it is not worth it. It is much easier to run two operating systems on a single machine than working with ruby on windows.

Comment: Can't agree more with @BroiSatse . Just use VMWare and run Linux locally....

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17762417/429758 for the solution.