# Rails server does not start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have installed `Ruby 2.2.2-x64` with `DevKit DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe` on `Windows 8.1.`

I updated the gem, installed `therubyracer`, `node.js`, `therubyrhino`, `sqllite3`, an my gem file have this line added:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]
```

My local gems are:

```
C:\Users\ogautier>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.2.1)
actionpack (4.2.1)
actionview (4.2.1)
activejob (4.2.1)
activemodel (4.2.1)
activerecord (4.2.1)
activesupport (4.2.1)
arel (6.0.0)
bigdecimal (1.2.7, 1.2.6)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.9.8, 1.9.7)
byebug (4.0.5)
coffee-rails (4.1.0)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
columnize (0.9.0)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.5.2)
globalid (0.3.5)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.3)
jbuilder (2.2.13)
jquery-rails (4.0.3)
json (1.8.2, 1.8.1)
loofah (2.0.2)
mail (2.6.3)
mime-types (2.5)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.6.1, 5.4.3)
multi_json (1.11.0)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2 x64-mingw32)
power_assert (0.2.3, 0.2.2)
psych (2.0.13, 2.0.8)
rack (1.6.1)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.1)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
railties (4.2.1)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
rubygems-update (2.4.6)
sass (3.4.13)
sass-rails (5.0.3)
sdoc (0.4.1)
sprockets (3.1.0)
sprockets-rails (2.3.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.10 x64-mingw32)
test-unit (3.0.9, 3.0.8)
therubyrhino (2.0.4)
therubyrhino_jar (1.7.6)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (2.0.1, 1.4.1)
turbolinks (2.5.3)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
tzinfo-data (1.2015.4)
uglifier (2.7.1)
web-console (2.1.2)
```

But the server does not start with rails server command, the error is listed below:

```
C:\Users\ogautier\RoR\holamundo>rails server
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb
:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/l
ib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/l
ib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb
:134:in `require'
        from C:/Users/ogautier/RoR/holamundo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (r
equired)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/com
mands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Is there someone that help me please?

Thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've gathered this seems to be a windows specific issue with SQLite3. I would suggest taking a look at [cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError) on ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails) as there seems to be some workarounds there to get by this issue.