# rails server gives: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to ruby & rails. I just created a new rails application & tried to run following command on the application root directory:

```
bin/rails server
```

but i'm getting following error on the console:

```
Yeasin@YEASIN-PC /g/wamp/www/railsBlog
$ bin/rails server
c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:i
n `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
        from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x86-mingw32/lib/s
qlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x86-mingw32/lib/s
qlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:76:in `require'
        from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:72:in `each'
        from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:61:in `each'
        from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:61:in `require'
        from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler.rb:134
:in `require'
        from g:/wamp/www/railsBlog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'

        from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from c:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/command
s.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I also tried following command as i am on windows.

```
ruby bin\rails server
```

But then i get

```
c:\Ruby22\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- binrails (LoadError)
```

Comment: Did you run the `bundle install`?

Comment: yes, i did, all the bundles got installed with out error

Comment: Have you tried editing your gemspec file, as described here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17762417/3367343

Comment: Looks like a slight improvement but now giving following error: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11309697/