# Can't Start Rails Server in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie in ruby on rails. I'm currently installing Ruby on Rails.
I've done all the steps until : `bundle install`.
Then i type `rails server` to start the rails server. From what I read in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html, after i type `rails server`, it's supposed to show:

```
$ cd commandsapp
$ bin/rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-08-07 02:00:01] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-08-07 02:00:01] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
[2013-08-07 02:00:01] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=69680 port=3000
```

but in my Command Line it show this, instead:
[image]

So the rails server is not running and when i type `localhost:3000` or `localhost:8000` in the browser, it says unable to connect(probably because the server isn't running).

Sorry my bad language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a rails app and change into that directory before you can run the server.  Try this:

```
rails new commandsapp    # the name can be anything you want
cd commandsapp
rails server
```

"rails new " creates a new folder with the default rails layout (app, db, log etc).

Comment: Ohh so I have to cd first, I've already create app named "MySite". After I Cd "MySite" and then type rails server, it's then shows new error. The Error: 'require' : cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 3):

The Error: 'require' : cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
==> You must insert gem sqlite3/sqlite3_native into gemfile, then bundle install again. Try with rails server.