# Sqlite Ruby Server Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

When I am trying to run the rails server command, I end up getting this, Does any one know how to fix this, please, thank you so much.

```
D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb :6:in 'require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError) from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/l ib/sqlite3.rb:6:in 'rescue in ' from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/l ib/sqlite3.rb:2:in '' from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r untime.rb:76:in 'require' from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r untime.rb:76:in 'block (2 levels) in require' from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r untime.rb:72:in 'each' from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r untime.rb:72:in 'block in require' from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r untime.rb:61:in 'each' from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r untime.rb:61:in 'require' from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.r b:134:in 'require' from D:/hello/test_app/config/application.rb:7:in '' from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/com mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in 'require' from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/com mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in 'block in server' from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/com mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in 'tap' from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/com mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in 'server' from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/com mands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in 'run_command!' from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/com mands.rb:17:in '' from bin/rails:4:in 'require' from bin/rails:4:in ''
```

Comment: see this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this and it did not work any other ideas, I appreciate the help ;)

Comment: before you try to run the server can you try running 'bundle install' and/or 'bundle update' from within the directory in which you have installed Rails. After this try creating a new Rails project and then run 'ruby script/rails server' from within the directory of your newly created Rails application.