# Ruby On Rails server initiation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have been following the [tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) on how to learn Ruby On Rails basics. I have installed the latest 2.2.3 version and ran "gem install rails". I have successfully created a new project, but I have got an error when tried to run a server with "rails server" command. I received these errors:

```
 C:\Users\Kothas\Desktop\rubyonrails\myproject>rails server
 c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.r:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
 from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/ib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/
 untime.rb:76:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/
 untime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/
 untime.rb:72:in `each'
    from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/
 untime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/
 untime.rb:61:in `each'
    from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/
 untime.rb:61:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.
 b:134:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Kothas/Desktop/rubyonrails/myproject/config/application.r
 :7:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/co
 mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/co
 mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/co
 mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/co
 mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/co
 mands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/co
 mands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

How can I fix these problems and start my application?

**EDIT**
I managed to fix sqlite3 errors, but the new ones showed 
    "cannot load such file -- nokogirl (LoadError)"

Comment: For Nokogiri, make sure the gem installed. Follow these steps: http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#windows

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your application is having difficulty accessing your sqlite installation through the sqlite3 gem -  try this answer: [cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError) on ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: I have changed "s.require_paths=["lib"]" to "s.require_paths= ["lib/sqlite3_native"]", but errors are still the same.

Comment: Have you made sure sqlite is installed on your machine? https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: I think so. I copied "sqlite3.def" and "sqlite3.dll" files to C:\Ruby22-x64\bin