# Docker dependency issue: Rake aborted! LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, gemfile, bundle-install, docker-build

I am having issues trying to solve this dependency issue. I have sqlite3 in my gemfile and I can see it installed, even when I run `gem list` (inside my docker container). But when I generate my dependencies with docker build, then run my project in a container, I get the following error when trying to run `rake test`

```
 root@401a61839c07:/app# rake test
    rake aborted!
    LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
```

Here is the build and you can clearly see that sqlite is installed.

```
docker build -f DependenciesDockerfile -t visual-base .
.
.
.
Step 12 : RUN bundle install --without development
---> Running in 623d8b439808
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Installing rake 10.5.0
Installing i18n 0.7.0
Installing json 1.8.3
Installing minitest 5.8.4
Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
Installing activesupport 4.1.6
Installing builder 3.2.2
Installing erubis 2.7.0
Installing actionview 4.1.6
Installing rack 1.5.5
Installing rack-test 0.6.3
Installing actionpack 4.1.6
Installing mime-types 2.99.1
Installing mail 2.6.3
Installing actionmailer 4.1.6
Installing activemodel 4.1.6
Installing arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Installing activerecord 4.1.6
Installing execjs 2.6.0
Installing autoprefixer-rails 6.3.3.1
Installing bcrypt 3.1.11
Installing sass 3.2.19
Installing bootstrap-sass 3.3.5
Installing climate_control 0.0.3
Installing cocaine 0.5.8
Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Installing railties 4.1.6
Installing coffee-rails 4.0.1
Installing jquery-rails 3.1.4
Using bundler 1.8.0
Installing hike 1.2.3
Installing multi_json 1.11.2
Installing tilt 1.4.1
Installing sprockets 2.12.4
Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.3
Installing rails 4.1.6
Installing commontator 4.10.5
Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
Installing responders 1.1.2
Installing warden 1.2.6
Installing devise 3.5.6
Installing devise-bootstrap-views 0.0.8
Installing gretel 3.0.8
Installing jbuilder 2.4.1
Installing kgio 2.10.0
Installing mimemagic 0.3.0
Installing net-ldap 0.14.0
Installing paperclip 4.3.5
Installing pg 0.18.4
Installing polyamorous 1.1.0
Installing raindrops 0.16.0
Installing rdoc 4.2.2
Installing rmagick 2.13.3
Installing sass-rails 4.0.5
Installing sdoc 0.4.1
Installing sqlite3 1.3.11
Installing squeel 1.2.3
Installing turbolinks 2.5.3
Installing uglifier 2.7.2
Installing unicorn 5.0.1
Bundle complete! 28 Gemfile dependencies, 63 gems now installed.
Gems in the group development were not installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Post-install message from rdoc:
Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:

<= 1.8.6 : unsupported
 = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
 = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
>= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
Post-install message from rmagick:
Please report any bugs. See https://github.com/gemhome/rmagick/compare/RMagick_2-13-2...master and https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/issues/18
 ---> 901bbde8aa4f
Removing intermediate container 623d8b439808
Successfully built 901bbde8aa4f

2.2.3 in visual-automation/ on master 
› docker build -t visual .                                                                  
Sending build context to Docker daemon 112.3 MB
Step 1 : FROM visual-base
 ---> 901bbde8aa4f
Step 2 : MAINTAINER
 ---> Running in bd02c1f718e7
 ---> 02f76881207c
Removing intermediate container bd02c1f718e7
Step 3 : ADD . /app
 ---> 4f80ec7fccce
Removing intermediate container 6d73bdc55fde
Step 4 : RUN sed -i.bak 's/user www-data;/user root;/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
 ---> Running in df22155ce2b7
 ---> aa9442d89c9e
Removing intermediate container df22155ce2b7
Step 5 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in f839dd6707ce
 ---> d197974fa925
Removing intermediate container f839dd6707ce
Successfully built d197974fa925

2.2.3 in repo/ on master 
› docker run -it visual /bin/bash                                                           
root@401a61839c07:/app# rake test
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
/app/vendor/cache/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require'
/app/vendor/cache/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/cache/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/2.2/sqlite3_native
/app/vendor/cache/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3.rb:4:in `require'
/app/vendor/cache/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
root@401a61839c07:/app#
```

Here is the output of `gem list` when run inside the container

```
root@69296d7eec2a:/app# gem list     

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.1.6)
actionpack (4.1.6)
actionview (4.1.6)
activemodel (4.1.6)
activerecord (4.1.6)
activesupport (4.1.6)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
autoprefixer-rails (5.2.1.1)
bcrypt (3.1.10)
bigdecimal (1.2.6)
bootstrap-sass (3.3.5)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.8.0)
climate_control (0.0.3)
cocaine (0.5.8)
coffee-rails (4.0.1)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
commontator (4.10.5)
devise (3.5.1)
devise-bootstrap-views (0.0.5)
dotenv (1.0.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.5.2)
foreman (0.77.0)
gretel (3.0.8)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.3)
jbuilder (2.3.1)
jquery-rails (3.1.3)
json (1.8.3, 1.8.1)
kgio (2.9.3)
mail (2.6.3)
mime-types (2.6.1)
mimemagic (0.3.0)
minitest (5.8.4, 5.4.3)
multi_json (1.11.2)
net-ldap (0.11)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
paperclip (4.3.5)
pg (0.18.3)
polyamorous (1.1.0)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (2.0.8)
rack (1.5.5)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.1.6)
railties (4.1.6)
raindrops (0.15.0)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
responders (1.1.2)
rmagick (2.13.3)
sass (3.2.19)
sass-rails (4.0.5)
sdoc (0.4.1)
sprockets (2.12.4)
sprockets-rails (2.3.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.11)
squeel (1.2.3)
test-unit (3.0.8)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (1.4.1)
turbolinks (2.5.3)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
uglifier (2.7.1)
unicorn (4.9.0)
warden (1.2.3)
```

I have seen temporary solutions by editing gemspecs but once you fix one, another similar error pops up. I must be missing something but it appears everything is in order.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Worked but now getting a new error: root@5824a83b7a06:/app# rake test
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- kgio_ext
/app/vendor/cache/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/app/vendor/cache/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/cache/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of the ruby gem https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby It says

> This module allows Ruby programs to interface with the SQLite3 database engine (www.sqlite.org). You must have the SQLite engine installed in order to build this module.

I think the issue here is that your docker container doesn't have the sqlite3 engine installed, so when the gem tries to call out to the native code it can't.

Verify that you have a line like
`RUN apt-get sqlite3` in your Dockerfile.