# Can't load sqlite3 for Ruby on Rails 5 for Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

Just installed Ruby on Rails 5 on Windows 10. I tried to run the rails server but it gave me the error below. I've tried a bunch of different solutions but nothing seems to work, probably because most of the suggestions were before RoR4. I've updated my PATH/environment variable and extracted the DLL and executable from the sqlite website and put that into my directory, ran `bundle install`...

```
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Tim/Documents/GitHub/event-registration-system/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails)?

Comment: Hm...I did try that before I posted here and it didn't work, but now it's working but giving me a different error when I run localhost:3000

Comment: Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall the sqlite3 gem? Also, how is sqlite3 referenced in your gemfile?

Comment: Yep, tried that. In the gemfile: `gem 'sqlite3'`

Comment: Ended up just reinstalling everything with RailsInstaller which worked. Thank you for all of your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just uninstalling everything and then using [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en) to set up my Rails environment for Windows and this problem was resolved. Rails 5 does work with sqlite now.

I'm not sure what the problem was, but this was the solution that worked for me. Wanted to post it here in case anyone else was experiencing this on the newer versions of the language or framework.