# cannot load such file — sqlite3/sqlite3_native

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I want to run rails server for my app it shows following error. I need help to identifies where the error

```
C:\Sites\app1>rails s
Traceback (most recent call last):
    22: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    21: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    20: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    18: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    17: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    16: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    15: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    14: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
    13: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
    12: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `block in perform'
    11: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `require'
    10: from C:/Sites/app1/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
     8: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
     7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
     6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
     5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
     4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
     3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
     2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3\_native (LoadError) on ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your gems are installed correctly and using correct versions of sqlite. Check you have this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'sqlite3',  '~> 1.3.11'
```

Then from root of your project run

```
bundle install
```

You may also need to run this if you have not already.

```
rails db:create db:migrate #this is for rails >= 5
```

or

```
rake db:create db:migrate  #rails <= 4.2
```