# Ruby failing to run after upgrading (sqlite3_native LoadError); sqlite3 not upgrading properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

I have upgraded to ruby 2.5.0 but I am having conflicts everywhere. I have checked previous posts on stack overflow such as:

[Ruby on Rails - "Add 'gem sqlite3'' to your Gemfile"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350837/ruby-on-rails-add-gem-sqlite3-to-your-gemfile)

[cannot load such file — sqlite3/sqlite3_native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552181/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native)

[cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError) on ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails)

https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/137

But none of them are working for me. My issue is similar to these posts in that after I run rails server after a long error message the last few lines read:

`1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in 'block in require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in 'require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)`

I have tried creating a new project, reinstalling sqlite3 through gem and minigw itself, reinstalling rails and ruby. I have tried most of the instructions in the previous questions but nothing works. SQLite3 version 3.25.2, Ruby 2.5.3, rails 5.2.1

Sorry, this might be a simple fix but I am a complete beginner to ruby and I have been trying different things for a few hours now. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49736971/4685144, you should now be able to install sqlite3 using git:

`gem 'sqlite3', git: 'https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby'`

Then `bundle install`