# New to ruby on rails, Getting error while run 'bundler exec rails server' command in cmd. Any idea how to resolve this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have just install ruby on rails and create test_app and try to check http://localhost:3000 but nothings happen so I investigate this issue and find out need to run 'bundler exec rails server' command. But when i exec this command getting error below. Please help to understand what I missing or I have done anything wrong?
Error coming from "C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32"

C:\Site\test_app>bundler exec rails server
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
    43: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    42: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
    41: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
    40: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
    39: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    38: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    37: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    36: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    35: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    34: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    33: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    32: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    31: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    30: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    29: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    28: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    27: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    26: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
    25: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
    24: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
    23: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
    22: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    21: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    20: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    19: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    18: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    17: from C:/Site/test_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    15: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    14: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    13: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    12: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    11: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    10: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:79:in `require'
     9: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     8: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
     7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:71:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:71:in `require'
     5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
     3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
     2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
     1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
```

Comment: Error message is pretty clear: `: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)`

Comment: But what I have to do for resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3\_native (LoadError) on ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Not working above solution as well :(

Comment: `Not working above solution` wont work. Write all steps you took and commands you wrote to arrive at this error.