# Rails can't install gem sqlite

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for
inspection.
Results logged to
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0'` succeeds before bundling.

I tried to install earlier version on sqlite, not working.
Tried one of the solutions from stackoverflow :

gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'

getting this error
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command sqlite3,

Please help i'm new in Rails , this is my first project in rails.

Comment: what happens when you run `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0'`?

Comment: do you have a Gemfile in your rails project?

Answer (score 0):

Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to `Gemfile` in the root directory of your rails project. Then run `bundle install` and it should install `sqlite` and make it available to use in your rails project.

Answer (score 0):

Specify `git` and `branch` for the gem `sqlite3` in your `Gemfile` should fix the problem.

```
gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"
```

For more info
https://medium.com/@declancronje/installing-and-troubleshooting-ruby-on-rails-sqlite3-windows-10-fix-87c8886d03b

[cannot load such file — sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError) Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249153/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-ruby-on-rails/50680295)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `gem 'sqlite3'` with  `gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.11'` which is in Gemfile in the root directory of your rails project. Then run bundle install.

Comment: This would be better as a comment because it's still unclear as to whether downgrading the gem would be a solution