# multiple gems error when attempting to run rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I installed rails and updated ruby - ever since I cannot get my server to run. I have also recently installed bootstrap. The spit out i get in my terminal is below when i run `rails s`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    43: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    42: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    41: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    40: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    39: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    38: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    37: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    36: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    35: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    34: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    33: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    32: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    31: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    30: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    29: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    28: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    27: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    26: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
    25: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    24: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    23: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    22: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    21: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    20: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    19: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    18: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    17: from c:/Sites/duck-duck-jeep/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
    15: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    14: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    13: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
    12: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
    11: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    10: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
     9: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     8: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
     7: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     6: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
     5: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
     3: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
     2: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     1: from c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
```

c:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)

also, here is my gemfile:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 3.2'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.2.1'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'duktape'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3\_native (LoadError) on ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails

Comment: yes, i saw these but it did not remedy my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gem uninstall sqlite3 --all
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3
gem inst sqlite3 --platform ruby
```