# I cannot connect "localhost:3000" in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am using a command prompt on Windows 7. I can connect to `localhost:3000` on the first time. But when I try to connect again, it shows an error.

I typed this list. It reported normal.

```
"ruby -v"
"rails -v"
"gem -v"
"bundler -v"
"rails new simpleblog"
"cd simpleblog"
"bundle install"
```

But when I typed `"rails s"`, it reported this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        21: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        20: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        19: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rai
ls/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        18: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rai
ls/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        17: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rai
ls/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        16: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:
387:in `dispatch'
        15: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/inv
ocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        14: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/com
mand.rb:27:in `run'
        13: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rai
ls/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
        12: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rai
ls/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
        11: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rai
ls/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `block in perform'
        10: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rai
ls/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `require'
         9: from C:/Users/DaNinnart/simpleblog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top
(required)>'
         8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
         7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'

         6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
         5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in
 require'
         4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
         3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2
 levels) in require'
         2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'

         1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw
32/lib/sqlite3.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb
:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/2.6/sqlite3_native (LoadError)

        22: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        21: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        20: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rai
ls/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        19: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rai
ls/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        18: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rai
ls/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        17: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:
387:in `dispatch'
        16: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/inv
ocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        15: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/com
mand.rb:27:in `run'
        14: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rai
ls/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
        13: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rai
ls/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
        12: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rai
ls/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `block in perform'
        11: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.1/lib/rai
ls/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `require'
        10: from C:/Users/DaNinnart/simpleblog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top
(required)>'
         9: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
         8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'

         7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
         6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in
 require'
         5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
         4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2
 levels) in require'
         3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'

         2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw
32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
         1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw
32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb
:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Any help from this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails

Comment: The path sqlite3/sqlite3_native must be wrong

Comment: Seems the first comment suits your situation, just search the solution for Windows there

Comment: Thank you for all comments.