# Unable to start the Webrick server with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

When I enter 'rails server' on the command line, I get the following error -

```
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in
 `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x86-mingw32/lib/sq
lite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x86-mingw32/lib/sq
lite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler.rb:133
:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Deepzster/Desktop/csa/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (requ
ired)>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/command
s.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I already tried re-installing and uninstalling Rails, and I read somewhere that this was supposed to be a 64-bit issue, however, I didn't get this to work even when I installed the 32-bit version. Is there any way I could fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800920/error-no-such-file-to-load-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror/6126062#6126062

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3\_native (LoadError) on ruby on rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be similar to this question

[cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError) on ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails)

Perhaps try the suggestions there and see if that helps?

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm able to start the server now.