# Rails server cannot start in cmd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am trying to load the WEBrick rails server but I keep getting the following. Please advice on what can be done.

```
C:\dev>cd nguza_app

C:\dev\nguza_app>rails server


C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:i
n `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x86-mingw32/lib/s
qlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x86-mingw32/lib/s
qlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler/runtim
e.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.1/lib/bundler.rb:134
:in `require'
        from C:/dev/nguza_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/command
s.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: seems to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the SQLite dependencies for windows.

Please see [Error "no such file to load" -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800920/error-no-such-file-to-load-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror/6126062#6126062)